# Listview - OnItemClickListener() acts in more items

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I have to hide a TextView on click on an item in a `Listview`.

So my problem is that is when I click an item the toast generated is right while the view to hide is modified every 6 item.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();

TextView selected_item = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
selected_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.show();

}
});
```

here some screenshot:

before click:

[image]

after click:

[image]

How can i fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: read about listview recycling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945563/how-listviews-recycling-mechanism-works

Comment: ... and if you need help fixing the issue, post your adapter `getView()` code as well.